# How to perform sporadic merging of one branch into another

Tags: git, gitlab, squash, git-squash

I develop on a branch `dev` and every couple of weeks want to merge the current state into a branch `staging`. It seems I didn't think this through enough, because now that I want to do this for the second time I get a conflict, since the last common ancestor is still from when I split `dev` off -- and the first difference was added to `staging` in a separate commit.

I used a gitlab merge request in both cases, with the `squash commits` box checked.

Is my approach inherently wrong and I need to switch to something different, or is there a way to make it work?

---

As a picture: The `v_0.2` merge fails. What I want is to do is a cherry pick of features 5-7, and I had hoped that gitlab would understand that since I had already merged features 1-4. But it doesn't.

[image]

---

As console output: `ffc9a2c` Is both branch's last common parent (apparently, the merge that happened there put that commit properly as the new parent), after which I started the merging scheme I described above. You can see `staging` in its entirety from that point onwards. I omitted most of `dev`, since it's just really long.

```
git log from staging:
*   5ac9823 Merge branch 'dev' into 'staging'
|\  
| * 50bac27 Code update for v1.rc0.0
|/  
*   5f38284 Merge branch 'dev' into 'staging'
|\  
| *   ffc9a2c Merge branch 'formatting_fix' into 'dev'


git log from dev:
*   176971e Merge branch 'doctest_fix' into 'dev'
|\  
| * 4f0a423 Fix bug for doctest in filters.py
.
.
.
*   945d9ab Merge branch 'return_codes' into 'dev'  # v1.rc0.0 took place here
|\  
| * aed6133 Replace return codes 
.
.
.
|  
*   ffc9a2c Merge branch 'formatting_fix' into 'dev'
|\  
| * 0451416 Improving Error Message Quality
```

Comment: I think your problem might be the `squash commits` box. You did not merge the commits `feature_1` to `feature_4` directly, but a new, squashed commit that introduces the same changes. The `v_0.2` merge now has conflicts since you try to merge another squashed commit, partly introducing the same changes. Can you show an actual graph of your repository, like `gitk` or `git log --graph` shows it?

Comment: I'll try to append the relevant logs from staging and dev. The thing is, I might do hotfixes on staging that won't be in dev, so I can't assume that their hashes can be the same. Will that not be a problem? And if it isn't why should a squashed commit be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `squash commits` box. You did not merge the commits `feature_1` to `feature_4` directly, but a new, squashed commit that introduces the same changes. The `v_0.2` merge now has conflicts since you try to merge another squashed commit, partly introducing the same changes.

From gits perspective, when you try to merge `dev` into `stable` with `v_0.2`, there are changes on the same files in `stable` that are not on `dev` (from the squashed merge commit) as well as changes in `dev` that are not on `stable` (new changes as well as changes from `feature_1` to 4, since these *commits* are not part of `stable`s history, only the changes have been introduced).

I think the best solution here would be not so squash the changes from `dev` when merging them to `stable`. You could also solve this via merging `stable` into `dev` or rebasing `dev` on `stable`, but this would make things even more confusing.

The hashes do not have to be the same; it is no problem to deploy hotfixes on staging and not taking them to develop (from a git perspective. In terms of a clean workflow, it's at least questionable to fix something and *not* merge it back to develop).

Comment: Alright, I'll try your suggestion and report back if it works. I am a bit sad that squashing won't work though, reverting changes on staging would be a lot easier if its history only included version updates and hotfixes.

Comment: I see your point there. There are controversial opinions on squashing (as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139783/gitflow-squash-commits-when-merging-from-develop-to-master#41298098)). I'm not entirely sure these conflicts cannot be prevented otherwise; your workflow only seems to be problematic when `feature_5,6,7` touch the same files as `feature_1..4`.

Comment: Setting `merge.conflictstyle diff3` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417656/should-diff3-be-default-conflictstyle-on-git)) helps to unterstand what is going on: when I recreate your case, it shows different changes in HEAD and `dev`, while the merged common ancestor is empty. Since different things were added on both branches in the same place, a conflict is inevitable.

Comment: I tested your approach and could recreate your results. Thanks for your help and time =)